# Equivalent definition of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I've come across the following two definitions of random variables and am trying to figure out if they are equivalent or not. Let $\Omega$ denote our sample space and $\mathscr{F}$ denote our $\sigma$-algebra.

1. A random variable $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}, \; X^{-1}(-\infty, a] \in \mathscr{F}$;
2. A random variable $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that for any Borel set $B \subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathscr{F}$.

I have a (very) basic understanding of what Borel sets are, but I fail to see how (and why / why not) these two would be equivalent. I have read that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all Borel sets) is the same as the one generated by intervals of the form $(-\infty, a]$, but I do not see the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that in order to verify that $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{F}$ for all Borel sets $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, it is enough to verify that $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{F}$ for all $B\in\mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

To see why this is true, just note that if $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $\mathcal{A}$ generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{F}$ for all $B\in\mathcal{A}$, then

1. $\mathcal{E}:=\{B\subseteq\mathbb{R}\mid X^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{F}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and
2. $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{E}$.

From this we can conclude that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\sigma(\mathcal{A})\subseteq\mathcal{E}$ or in other words $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathscr{F}$ holds for all Borel sets.

Comment: ... all intervals of the form $(-\infty,a]$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: hello I'm trying to prove the same equivalence but I don't seem to understand your proof , could you tell me where can I find such a proof (any book or link ) ?